# Can I Prevent Multiple Static directories in Express producing a 404?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am attempting to serve files from 2 different folders, the purpose for this is that I would like have my admin and client folders completely separated.

I have the following code to initiate the folders, however as express looks for `example.css`, if it doesn't find it in the first */static* directory, it sends a 404 error and then it does find it in the second directory.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static")); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/alternate_static"));
```

Is there any way I can make it so express doesn't serve the 404 unless it can't find the file in any of the multiple folders or is this a potential issue i should post on the gitHub?

**Edit:** To try make myself clearer... If I have a directory as follows;

```
/static
/alternate_static/index.js
```

and I try load index.js, Express will first look in `/static` then it will log a 404 error because it cannot find the file, then it will search `/alternate_static` and it will find the file and proceed to serve the file. I am hoping to stop the first 404 from happening.

**EDIT: Solved. it seems that it was some kind of cache issue with the favicon**

Thanks

Comment: Works for me, files that aren't stored in the first static directory but exist in the second are found successfully.

Comment: Yeah, it does **work**, but with issues as far as i can tell, however If express doesn't find the file in the first static route it will send a 404, then it will find it... I will modify my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Are you sure that the 404 is being caused by the request for `example.css` and not, say, `favicon.ico`? I don't see how Express could log _two_ lines for _one_ request.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It turns out you were correct, i'm not exactly sure why it wanted a favicon as I did not have express set to read one, I can only assume chrome had something cached to call it for the localhost.

Regardless, you have solved my issue, thank you very much for the suggestion!

Comment: It's common for browsers to request `favicon.ico` without you explicitly asking it do to so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will do exactly what you want.

The way Express' routing logic works is linear: it will simply check matching routes in the order in which they were `use`'d by your application =)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have adjusted my question to make it a little clearer, hopefully you can take a moment to have another look and offer some more insight, thanks